# how to find matched value in 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a char variable. I want to find out in 2D char array has equal element to my char variable and if there has one element I want to get index number of that element

Comment: Two `for` loops and some `if`.

Comment: If it is a genuine 2D array you'll get 2 index numbers - but you could use a 1D array instead and keep track of how long each row/column should be (e.g. like pixels in an image).

Comment: @xenteros Your solution is incomplete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a class that holds two indices. Your method will return an instance of this class.

```
char array[][] = new char[10][10];    

class Tuple //helper class
{
    public int i,  j;
    Tuple(int i, int j)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}
public Tuple matches(char c) //return indices (Tuple-instance) or null if not found
{

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] == c)
            {
                return new Tuple(i, j);
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through the 2D array. The below code shows the solution for array called "`myarray`" and `char` stored in variable called `mychar`. The coordinates of `mychar` will be displayed in console.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myarray[i].length; j++) {
        if (myarray[i][j] == mychar){
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + " " + String.valueOf(j));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```